# Python - how to generate wordlist from given characters of specific length

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary-attack

I want to perform a dictionary attack and for that I need word lists. How to generate word list from given characters of specific length ( or word length from min length to max length )? I have tried `itertools.combinations_with_replacements` and `itertools.permutations`, but it does not help. They does not have all the word lists that it should return. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you understand the concept behind a dictionary attack. The idea is to NOT generate all possible combinations (there are A LOT) but to use a file containing actual dictionary words (and other words that are likely passwords).

Answer (score 8):

Use [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
>>> import itertools
>>>
>>> chrs = 'abc'
>>> n = 2
>>>
>>> for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=n):
...     print ''.join(xs)
...
aa
ab
ac
ba
bb
bc
ca
cb
cc
```

To get word from min length to max length:

```
chrs = 'abc'
min_length, max_length = 2, 5    
for n in range(min_length, max_length+1):
    for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=n):
        print ''.join(xs)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a naïve implementation:

```
list='abcdefg'
depth=8

def generate(l,d):
  if d<1:
    return
  for c in l:
    if d==1:
      yield c
    else:
      for k in generate(l,d-1):
        yield c+k

for d in range(1,depth):
  for c in generate(list,d):
    print c
```

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet, so, to make a full list based on the itertools sample above:

```
import itertools
chrs='abc'
n=6
for i in range(1,n):
  for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=i):
    print ''.join(xs)
```

This way, you have all words from length 1 up to n in your list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

def allwords(chars, length):
    for letters in product(chars, repeat=length):
        yield ''.join(letters)

def main():
    letters = "abc"
    for wordlen in range(3, 5):
        for word in allwords(letters, wordlen):
            print(word)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

returns

```
aaa
aab
aac
aba
abb

...

ccbc
ccca
cccb
cccc
```

Answer (score -1):

def word_gen(start= 3,end= 3, elements = 1):
    """
    Hud Seidu Daannaa Wordlist gen
    MSC InfoSec, CEH"

```
README
#for start&end
#e.g. start= 3,end= 3
#means first words to last words should be 3 characters

#for elements
1 is asci
2 is numbers
3 is asci&numbers
"""
import itertools
#types of elements
if elements ==1: elements= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx'
if elements ==2: elements= '0123456789'
if elements== 3: elements= 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyx0123456789'
else: pass
wl = []
for i in range(start,end+1):
    for xs in itertools.product(elements, repeat=i):
        wl.append(''.join(xs))
return wl
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow. Can you also explain your answer?