# Wordlist generator in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

After a lot of searching and fails and lot of stress for being dumb, I am gonna to ask, how to build a wordlist generator in python?

My case
letters and numbers to use (abcdef0123456789)
length (72 chars)

to generate something like that:

"18516a9744529fcf5f01cc12b86fe5db614db6d688d826f20d501b343199f2de921a6310"

Comment: it can generate every possiblity of combination? (i know sounds insane)

Comment: You could also try this: `from random import randrange; ''.join(hex(randrange(16))[2:] for _ in range(72))`.

Answer (score 1):

Yep - every combination - following the example of the link I posted above:
[Random string generation with upper case letters and digits in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257441/random-string-generation-with-upper-case-letters-and-digits-in-python)

you could do:

```
import random

# same function as in the link, but size set to your desired length (72)
# instead of using the strings module, i'm just making a list of 
# allowable characters. there's cleaner ways to do this, but i wanted to 
# make it clear for you

def id_generator(size=72, chars= (['a','b','c','d', 'e', 'f','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'])):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
x = id_generator()
print x
```

Erm . . . If you're trying to generate the whole list of every possible combination, that's unlikely to go well, since there's about 5 x 10E86 possible combinations. Which is a lot.

Comment: I did that:


 import itertools
>>>
>>> chrs = 'abcef0123456789'
>>> n = 72
>>>
>>> for xs in itertools.product(chrs, repeat=n):
...     print ''.join(xs) '

credits:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559039/python-how-to-generate-wordlist-from-given-characters-of-specific-length)

Btw, its a lot of tries, and will take some time

There is a way to auto-save that full list in .txt after after all attempts?